# Can't find error in a complex IF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Excel there's an error in this formula but I can't find it.

```
=IF(AM8="Pass",(IF(SUM(AN8:AO8)=3,"Excellent performance. Keep it up.",IF(AND(FL8<>"",SUM(AS8:AU8)=0),"Excellent performance in "&FL8&" but can still improve in other subjects.",if(gs8<>"","Must work harder in " &gs8&" and aim higher next term.",if(sum(Ap8:AQ8)=3,"Good effort. Keep improving",if(sum(AR8:AS8)=3,"Just managed to pass. Need to focus on weak areas."))))),"Satisfactory performance. Overall improvement required"),if(and(BD8=true,sum(AN8:AR8)=3),"Passed in Main subjects. Must work harder in GP", "Very poor performance. Must work very hard."))
```

Any help to correct this formula and any suggestion as to a better way of doing this task will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you counted your parenthesis?

Comment: What does Excel suggest is the fix?

Comment: What is your task?

Comment: Have a look with this tool (I just found it.) http://excelformulabeautifier.com/

Comment: @StevenDavison Interesting and helpful tool

Comment: What is the nature of the error (formula structure, not returning the expected result)?

Comment: This is why I like the IFS function in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(AM8="Pass",(IF(SUM(AN8:AO8)=3,"Excellent performance. Keep it up.",IF(AND(FL8<>"",SUM(AS8:AU8)=0),"Excellent performance in "&FL8&" but can still improve in other subjects.",IF(GS8<>"","Must work harder in " &GS8&" and aim higher next term.",IF(SUM(AP8:AQ8)=3,"Good effort. Keep improving",IF(SUM(AR8:AS8)=3,"Just managed to pass. Need to focus on weak areas.","Satisfactory performance. Overall improvement required")))))),IF(AND(BD8=TRUE,SUM(AN8:AR8)=3),"Passed in Main subjects. Must work harder in GP", "Very poor performance. Must work very hard."))
```

`if(sum(AR8:AS8)=3,"Just managed to pass. Need to focus on weak areas."))))),"Satisfactory performance. Overall improvement required"),if(and(BD8=true,sum(AN8:AR8)=3),"Passed in Main subjects. Must work harder in GP", "Very poor performance. Must work very hard."))'

This is the part where the error is: You closed 5 if and wrote 2 values for the Value if False 
I have change it and fixed the Formula just test it.

Answer (score -4):

I think it's with regard to this part:

"Satisfactory performance. Overall improvement required"),if(and(BD8=true,sum(AN8:AR8)=3),"Passed in Main subjects. Must work harder in GP", "Very poor performance. Must work very hard."))

I think it might need an IF( in front of it, I don't have a lot of time to thoroughly look it over though.